# Phantomjs reloading same page for every 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, phantomjs, mocha-phantomjs

I want my phantomjs script to keep performing reloading/refreshing on given argument input domain `https://google.com` for every `5` seconds. How do i achieve that?

> phantomjs test.js https://google.com

- test.js

```
var page = require('webpage').create(),
    system = require('system'),
    address;

page.onAlert = function (msg) {
    console.log("Received an alert: " + msg);
};

page.onConfirm = function (msg) {
    console.log("Received a confirm dialog: " + msg);
    return true;
};

if (system.args.length === 1) {
    console.log("Must provide the address of the webpage");
} else {
    address = system.args[1];
    for(var i=0; i <= 10; i++){
    page.open(address, function (status) {
        if (status === "success") {
            console.log("opened web page successfully!");
            page.evaluate(function () {
                var e = document.createEvent('Events');
                e.initEvent('click', true, false);
                document.getElementById("link").dispatchEvent(e);
            });
        }
    }); }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`setTimeout`](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_settimeout_callback_delay_args) to call a function that loads the page a certain amount of time after it loads:

```
var page = require('webpage').create(),
    system = require('system'),
    address;

page.onAlert = function (msg) {
    console.log("Received an alert: " + msg);
};

page.onConfirm = function (msg) {
    console.log("Received a confirm dialog: " + msg);
    return true;
};

function loadPage() {
  if (system.args.length === 1) {
    console.log("Must provide the address of the webpage");
  } else {
    address = system.args[1];
    page.open(address, function (status) {
      if (status === "success") {
        console.log("opened web page successfully!");
        page.evaluate(function () {
          var e = document.createEvent('Events');
          e.initEvent('click', true, false);
          document.getElementById("link").dispatchEvent(e);
        });
      }
      setTimeout(loadPage, 5000) // Call the function loadPage again in 5 seconds
    });
  }
}

loadPage()
```